# Ruby on rails - wanting to add custom action, but controller is looking for ID parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm basically trying to create a custom action called `mass_update`, but when I try to browse to it, I get an error in the console indicating that `id=mass_update` is invalid. Here's what I'm working with

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :mailers do
    member do
        get "show_msg"
        get 'generate'
    end
end
get 'mailers/mass_update', to: 'mailers#mass_update'
```

.

```
#app/controllers/mailers_controller.rb
class MailersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_mailer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  ...

  def mass_update
  end
  ...
end
```

.

```
# $ rake routes | grep -i mass
                  mailers_mass_update GET    /mailers/mass_update(.:format)                        mailers#mass_update
```

.

```
# app/views/mailers/index.html.erb
<%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Mass Update'.html_safe, mailers_mass_update_path, remote: :true, class: "btn btn-success btn-sm"  %>
```

And everything looks fine as far as the routes go. No issues even on the view, but the minute I click on the button to go to `mailers/mass_update`, the controller throws an error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Mailer with
>   'id'=mass_update)

I get that this is the default/standard way, having the ID afterwards, but what happens if I want to get to `mass_update` without an ID?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Added this in between the resources block:

```
collection do 
  get 'mass_update'
end
```

and now the controller doesn't expect an ID. Perfect.

Answer (score 1):

[`resources`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resources) block were creating all the standard routes. One of them was for `show` actions, `GET mailers/:id`. And this route was being matched as it comes before your `get 'mailers/mass_update', to: 'mailers#mass_update'` route definition, and `id` value was set to `mass_update`. So add the route inside the `resources` block:

```
collection do 
  get 'mass_update'
end
```